# Is there a possible way to set price limit at amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a possible way to set price limit at amazon s3.
I've read about creating an alarm here
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-alarms.html
But It seems like an alarm when you exceed your free limits.
And I need to set amount of money for example to $10 and if bill is more than that - terminate service usage.(In case of dos attack for example I might notice  email alarm too late, or I might be travelling and don't have access to internet or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in the way you specify.

However, you may be able to approximate to it by setting up a process which (a) monitors the total billing so far and (b) does whatever action seems appropriate if the billing exceeds what you want. When you say "terminate service usage" you may not really mean "delete all my S3 files", for instance.

You should be aware that there is no guarantee that billing is updated every second, every minute, or even every hour. There is no business reason for Amazon to implement this and it adds to the complexity of their systems. All they care about is that the billing data *eventually* find their way to your account.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly enable such option on aws gui console. But you can shutdown system if your billing reach a specific limit through [AWS CLI.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html)

[usage-reports-instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/usage-reports-instance.html)

[new-programmatic-access-to-aws-billing-data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-programmatic-access-to-aws-billing-data/)